# Pulling Random Image From Directory with PHP

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to produce a random image on my 404 pages from a directory in my assets.  I found another thread using the code I'm using, but I have had zero luck getting this to work.

```
<h1>404 Page not Found</h1>
            <?php
                $imageDir = 'https://globalassets.provo.edu/image/404/';
                $images = glob($imageDir . '*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);
                $randomImage = $images[array_rand($images)];

            ?>
            <img src="<?php echo($randomImage); ?>" alt="" />
```

Any ideas?  If I try to print just $images it appears to give me a empty Array.

Comment: probably no access to that site

Comment: "Note: This function will not work on remote files as the file to be examined must be accessible via the server's filesystem." source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AH! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

I moved the 404 images folder into the same directory as my theme and everything is working now

the updated code looks like

```
<h1>404 Page not Found</h1>
            <?php
                $imageDir = '404/';
                $images = glob($imageDir . '*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);
                $randomImage = $images[array_rand($images)];

            ?>
            <img src="<?php echo($randomImage);  ?>" alt="" />
```

Comment: The problem with this system is the images only rotated if you 404'd from the root directory.

I switched to a JavaScript rotation that is working much better.